# ReactJs: Parent or child component responsible for processing data to render view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am just starting to learn ReactJS. I would like to know which is better given the scenario: The parent component makes a `GET` request to some server, returning a `JSON` object. I want to pass these attributes to a child component. However, not all of the JSON attributes can be rendered directly in the child component's view (I.e I cannot use `props.XXX` in the child component). Either the parent component runs the preprocessing code to package the data nicely for the child component, or the child component does the preprocessing before it renders it's own view.

Should the parent or the child component run the preprocessing code ?

Comment: All you have done is good, but I don't know if you are using Class Component or Functional component ? And when you are got the JSON , have you stored it in State of the parent  or how ? You need to put the json data in state but best option is using redux. https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started, https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I am using functional component for both parent and child. But I did realise one thing. If i place the processing function in the child component, the function will be called before the data is retrieved because the `UseEffect` hook to retrieve the data is run after the `render` method in parent component.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue parent.

```js
const Logic = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(...).then(setData).catch(...)
  }, [])
  return <View data={data.map((item) => ({...item, title: item.title.toUpperCase()})} />
}

const View = ({data}) => (
  <>
    {data.map(item => <div>{item.title</div>)}
  </>
)
```

Comment: `{data.map(transformData)}` transforms the data in the parent component. why do you have to call `{data.map(item => ...}` again in the `View` component ?

Comment: You can transform the data in the `Logic` component but you still have to map over the data in the child component if you are converting a list into a series of html elements.